# A button or box with mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

How can I make a button or something, where you can hover over the box or button and see a small page. Go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HGSUZwvFqG0 and hover over a name in the comments and you see what I mean :) thank you, please answer :)

Facebook has something similar if you hover over a name but I please you not to post this code. thx

I tried to make something with a modal box but it doesn't work like the thing on youtube.

On Facebook the box is fixed but on YouTube it isn't

Comment: Hey, welcome to StackOverflow! We're much more likely to be able to help you if you take a crack at the problem yourself and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Check the Stack Overflow [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist) for more information on asking the right questions. Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: I describe what I've tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd start off with something like this:

```
<div class="person">
    <a href="link.html">Name</a>
    <div class="info">Here is more information, add anything you want here</div>
</div>
```

Then in css:

```
.person{
   position:relative;
}
.person .info{
   position:absolute;
   //Change these to position the box wherever
   top:10px; 
   left:10px;
   display:none;
}
.person:hover .info{
   display:block;
}
```

This will show a link, that when hovered over, will show more info. It's rough, but is a good jumping off point. Adding some javascript could make this behave a little nicer, consider using something like hover intent for instance.

Comment: :/ I feel so dumb it's so easy :D thanks :) by the way, do you know how to make a database for a site? for log in

Comment: thanks do you know how to make a database for log in form? :)

Comment: It's best to post a new question for a new topic. But in this case I'd just google. If you are using php/mysql this isn't a bad place to start: http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/simple-registration-system-php-mysql/ But if that doens't use the technologies you want, There are plenty of other tutorials out there.

Comment: About my first question. How can I make this div always appear in the window. like when it is at the bottom I can't see it :/

Comment: I would like that div to appear so that I can see it, whereever it is, if it is at the bottom the box will be above,...

Comment: and it would be cool if the box appear right where I hover over the element. like if the link has 200 characters I want the box to appear right next to the mouse whereever I hover over the link :)

Comment: That is where Javascript will come in to play. You can use it to dynamically position the block. Again, search for it. Here is an answer that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294284/how-to-know-when-an-element-will-be-off-screen

Comment: :/ I don't understand it, I posted a new question on this topic

Comment: If you have time to take a look on a another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19601647/counter-in-javascript-and-html?noredirect=1#comment29095655_19601647 would be nice :) I'm so helpless at this point